# Nodejs : passport-local-mongoose's .plugin(...) doesn't do anything

Tags: node.js, mongoose, passport.js, passport-local

I'm trying to use `passport-local-mongoose` in order to register users in my MongoDB database. However it seems like it's not doing what it is supposed to.

**Model:**

```
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: {
        type: String,
        ...
    },
});

userSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose, {usernameField: 'email'});

userSchema.statics = {
    ...
}

userSchema.methods = {
    ...
}

var User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
module.exports = User;
```

**Controller:**

```
exports.registerAction = async (req, res, next) => {
    const user = new User({ email: req.body.email });
    User.register(user, req.body.password, function() {
        res.send('It works!');
    });
```

As I understand it, Passport is supposed to implement the `register` method on User, but here `User.register` stays `undefined`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by myself.

The `userSchema.plugin(...)` call has to be made **after** defining`userSchema.statics = {…}` and `userSchema.methods = {…}`.

I guess `.plugin(...)` tries to use the `statics` or `methods` property (or both), and initializes them as an new object. Then, when we call `userSchema.statics = {…}` (or `methods`), it simply erases what `.plugin(...)` had created.

Comment: That's what `userSchema.statics = {}` does: it assigns a new object to the `statics` property (and the previous object, including the parts that the plugin added, will be unreferenced). You can also use `userSchema.statics.myStaticMethod = ...` to prevent that.

Comment: Yes, I just didn't realize that `plugin(...)` was setting properties of `statics` and `methods`… I've never seen clearly stated anywhere.
Thanks for your suggestion. I was also looking for a way to extend the object without overwriting it, without repeating `userSchema.statics` for every function, but I couldn't find the proper syntax.

Comment: `Object.assign(userSchema.statics, { ... })` would probably work as well.